# Passing parameter values to interactive report query in another page in apex 5 but report output shows blank

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am selecting the values from the select list and passing it to the Interactive report query in another report.

I have 4 parameters and each one is a select list value.

Once I select all 4 parameters I press submit button and It will redirect to another page and execute the interactive report query based on selected parameters.

But report output shows blank.

When I checked the session tab, no values are passed to the report page.

Please help me in parameterized report of this scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Expected some kind of code for better explanation and understanding of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1 : You can set hidden items values of page which is having interactive report using redirection branch and then these hidden items can be work as parameters/bind variables in interactive report in query.

Navigation : page designer > Legacy Component View [Deprecated] -> branches -> Create/edit existing branch
  [image]
Approach 2:  You can set hidden items values of page which is having interactive report using Button Action as :Redirect to page in this application and then these hidden items can be work as parameters/bind variables in interactive report in query.

Navigation : page designer > Legacy Component View [Deprecated] > edit button   >Action When Button Clicked (section)

[image]

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Reply. I was trying to implement this but didn't found the navigation. Can you please provide that for both the option.